# Convert a dictionary with non serializable elements into bytes and back

Tags: python, dictionary, serialization, flask, charm

I have to implement the following scenario for the needs of my project.

1. I am retrieving a dict from a function (whose elements are not
   serializable)
2. I want to convert the above mentioned dict into bytes (so I can send it back as a response to the client)
3. Next, I want these bytes received by the client (in step 2) to be sent again through my web service, and convert again to its initial format (dict).

I tried to follow the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232011/convert-dictionary-to-bytes-and-back-again-python) by using `json.dumps` as follows:

```
cipher_text = hyb_abe.encrypt(master_public_key, fileInBase64Format, policy) #this function comes from the charm-crypto framework and returns a dictionary
encrypted_bytes = json.dumps(cipher_text) # produces error TypeError: Object of type 'Element' is not JSON serializable
```

The code of `hyb_abe.encrypt` function is [here](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/adapters/abenc_adapt_hybrid.py)

but I am getting

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Element' is not JSON serializable
```

What could be a workaround for my case?

**EDIT**

Photo of the value of the dictionary in debug mode

[image]

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Hi @Prune , thanks for your interest :) . I think everything was pretty clear but I updated my answer as you can see

Comment: Hi @NickAth, what Prune was inferring was that we need to see a chunk of the information you are trying to dump to json. Thanks for showing us the function you are using. That's great! But at a minimum, we also need to see an example of the data so that we know how it could be causing the error (e.g. cannot serialize).

Comment: @NickAth JSON has the advantage of being really fast when dumping, but can be picky if its not dealing with string data or straightforward structures. How would you feel about using pickle instead?

Comment: Hi @DanielScott yes I have tried with pickle as follows data = pickle.dumps(cipher_text) but I am getting TypeError: can't pickle pairing.Element objects. Unfortunately the content of the dictionary was too big to paste it in a pastebin so I attach a photo of the debugger

Comment: I can't find where the photo of the debugger is.

Comment: @DanielScott I have attached it :)

Comment: Could you pastebin the contents of element 'C'? From your screenshot, we can see the 2 elements that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Look's like your solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251642/how-to-serialize-store-the-ciphertext-encrypted-by-hybrid-cpabe-bsw07-in-charm

Comment: @DanielScott Omg I would not expect to find the same question on SO ! Many thanks

Comment: Glad that helps!